# Whenever I download an .sh-file gedit opens up

Tags: 14.10, gedit

Whenever I download an .sh-file gedit opens up and then freezes. Why?

Comment: What is the script?

Comment: Do you want to run the .sh file?

Comment: I know how to run .sh files over the command line, I just wonder why gedit always opens up and freezes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `gedit` opens up after the download is complete, that's because your browser is set up to open downloaded files automatically and to open them in the system's default application.

If `gedit` opens up because you double-clicked on the `.sh` file in `nautilus`, that's because of the default behavior of `nautilus`, which is to open `.sh` files in the system's default text editor rather than to run them.

To change `nautilus`' default behavior:

1. Open Files from the Unity Launcher
2. On the Unity Panel, click on "Edit" > "Preferences"
3. Select the "Behavior" tab and under "Executable Text Files" select "Run executable files when they are opened" and click on the "Close" button.

On why `gedit` freezes, it might be that the `.sh` file is **very** long.

If the `.sh` is not **very** long, it might be that it is encoded with some exotic encoding that `gedit` cannot handle.

If the `.sh` file is not encoded with any exotic encoding, try to reinstall / update gedit by running this command in a Terminal: `sudo apt-get remove gedit && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gedit`

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be a lot more intuitive for us newbies if Ubuntu did run .sh files per default?

Answer (score 1):

`sh` files aren't double-click executables; they need to be run from the terminal. (`/path/to/script.sh`) `sh` files can also be big. More than 10MB of text is sure to freeze up any text program for a while, until it can load all of the text.

Comment: sudo for a unknown script can be dangerous.

Comment: @A.B. OK, Mr. Critical. It's edited.

Comment: Come on, `gksudo` is just as dangerous. It's about to run the script with superuser privileges without it to see before.

Comment: @A.B. What would you like?

Comment: Let the `sudo` just gone.

Comment: @A.B. Okey Dokey.